# How to fix this insert? Don't work for me!

Tags: query, wpdb

I need to fix errors of this insert because this don't work in my script. I'm a beginner in WordPress SQL. Thanks

```
$wpdb->insert('wp_cadastrados', 
    array (
        'ID'            => NULL,
        'nome'          => $_POST['nome_cliente'],
        'email'         => $_POST['email_cliente'],
        'documento'     => $_POST['MeuCPFouRG'],
        'telefone'      => $_POST['MeuTelefone'],
        'curso'         => $_POST['CursoDesejado'],
        'valor_tot'     => number_format($_POST['ValorDoCurso'], 2),
        'quantidade'    => 1,
        'data_cad'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    ),
    array (
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%d',
        '%d',
        '%s'
    ) 
);
```

Comment: what is the error you getting from this script? try add global $wpdb before $wpdb->insert

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the value portion of the data parameter's column=>value pairs must be
 scalar.  If you pass an array (or object) as a value to be inserted you will generate a warning similar to `mysql_real_escape_string()` expects parameter 1 to be string, array given on line 880 in file 
/var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php".

Rather then above your code is looking correct with :

```
<?php $wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format ); ?>
```

So finally check that every `$_POST` are not in array format.